# How to check if a particular Objectid exists before posting it in the collection using nodejs mongodb and mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, ejs

Context: I am making a Product management system where an employee can issue an particular product and then it stores the product objectId into the issue collection and with some other fields. Uptill Now i can issue a particular product but i want to check if the product is already issued and if it is issued already then i want redirect to issueindex where user have to issue a product which is not issued already with an message that product is issued.

I tried with both findbyId method and findoOne() method but with both i am getting errors.

How do i compare the ObjectId of the product?

This is the error im getting while issuing a product which has been issued already i have logged a messaged into console and it shows it in terminal below.

I have attached code of post method which is responsible for the feature and models pf issue and product.

## Error And Log message

```
product already Issued
CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value ":id" at path "_id" for model "Prodcut"
    at model.Query.exec (C:\Users\shlok\Desktop\product_mngt_system\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4408:21)
    at model.Query.Query.then (C:\Users\shlok\Desktop\product_mngt_system\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4502:15)
    at issue_get (C:\Users\shlok\Desktop\product_mngt_system\controllers\issueController.js:9:6)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\shlok\Desktop\product_mngt_system\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\shlok\Desktop\product_mngt_system\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\shlok\Desktop\product_mngt_system\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\shlok\Desktop\product_mngt_system\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\Users\shlok\Desktop\product_mngt_system\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at param (C:\Users\shlok\Desktop\product_mngt_system\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:354:14)
    at param (C:\Users\shlok\Desktop\product_mngt_system\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:365:14)
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\shlok\Desktop\product_mngt_system\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:410:3)        
    at next (C:\Users\shlok\Desktop\product_mngt_system\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at Function.handle (C:\Users\shlok\Desktop\product_mngt_system\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3)
    at router (C:\Users\shlok\Desktop\product_mngt_system\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\shlok\Desktop\product_mngt_system\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (C:\Users\shlok\Desktop\product_mngt_system\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13) {
  messageFormat: undefined,
  stringValue: '":id"',
  kind: 'ObjectId',
  value: ':id',
  path: '_id',
  reason: Error: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters
      at new ObjectID (C:\Users\shlok\Desktop\product_mngt_system\node_modules\bson\lib\bson\objectid.js:59:11)
      at castObjectId (C:\Users\shlok\Desktop\product_mngt_system\node_modules\mongoose\lib\cast\objectid.js:25:12)
      at ObjectId.cast (C:\Users\shlok\Desktop\product_mngt_system\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema\objectid.js:279:12)
      at ObjectId.SchemaType.applySetters (C:\Users\shlok\Desktop\product_mngt_system\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1104:12)
      at ObjectId.SchemaType._castForQuery (C:\Users\shlok\Desktop\product_mngt_system\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1539:15)
      at ObjectId.SchemaType.castForQuery (C:\Users\shlok\Desktop\product_mngt_system\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1529:15)
      at ObjectId.SchemaType.castForQueryWrapper (C:\Users\shlok\Desktop\product_mngt_system\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1506:20)
      at cast (C:\Users\shlok\Desktop\product_mngt_system\node_modules\mongoose\lib\cast.js:331:32)
      at model.Query.Query.cast (C:\Users\shlok\Desktop\product_mngt_system\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4848:12)
      at model.Query.Query._castConditions (C:\Users\shlok\Desktop\product_mngt_system\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:1890:10)
      at model.Query.<anonymous> (C:\Users\shlok\Desktop\product_mngt_system\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:2147:8)
      at model.Query._wrappedThunk [as _findOne] (C:\Users\shlok\Desktop\product_mngt_system\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\query\wrapThunk.js:16:8)
      at C:\Users\shlok\Desktop\product_mngt_system\node_modules\kareem\index.js:370:33
      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11)
}
```

## Issue controller

```
const issue_post = (req, res) => {
const id = req.params.id;
  Issue.findOne({ product : id}, (err, product) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    if (product) {
      req.flash("error", "Product Already Issued");
      res.redirect("/products/issue/:id/issueindex");
      console.log("product already Issued");
    } else {
      const issue = new Issue({
        ename: req.body.ename,
        email: req.body.email,
        enumber: req.body.enumber,
        cnumber: req.body.cnumber,
        desig: req.body.desig,
        department: req.body.department,
        description: req.body.description,
        product: req.params.id,
      });
      issue
        .save()
        .then((result) => {
          console.log("Data entered");
          res.redirect("/products/issue/details");
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log("Data not entered");
          console.log(err);
        });
    }
  });
};
```

## issue Model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const issueSchema = new Schema({
    ename: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    enumber: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    cnumber: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    desig: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    department: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    status: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },  
    product: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Prodcut'
    },
    issueTime: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now()
    }
});

const Issue = mongoose.model('issue',issueSchema);

module.exports = Issue;
```

## Product Model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const productSchema = new Schema({
    prodid: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    manufacturer: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    category: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'category'
    },
    status: {
        type: String,
        default: 'In Stock'
    },
    coverImage: {
        type: Buffer,
        required: true
    },
    coverImageType: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
}, { timestamps: true });

productSchema.virtual('coverImagePath').get(function() {
    if (this.coverImage != null && this.coverImageType != null) {
      return `data:${this.coverImageType};charset=utf-8;base64,${this.coverImage.toString('base64')}`
    }
  });

const Prodcut = mongoose.model('Prodcut',productSchema);

module.exports = Prodcut;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I see some typos: `Prodcut` instead of `Product`

Comment: I fixed that typo but I didn't make any difference. Same error Is coming up. I think the issue is in the Id passing in findOne method and I don't have to fix that

Comment: Notice that you actually redirect to "/products/issue/:id/issueindex" - so mongoose actually ends up trying to cast the ":id" string to an ObjectId.

Comment: @IAmDranged  I redirected to a different page and it works great! But do you have any idea how could i redirect it to "/products/issue/:id/issueindex" this without getting issues?

Comment: You should redirect to `"/products/issue/"+id+"/issueindex"` - ie include the actual id in the url rather than the ":id" string. I'm assuming that the route you are redirecting to has a route param setup for the id part of the url. Hopefully that simple fix should be enough to clear up your problem.

Comment: Thanks man! that works fine now.

Comment: Have you considered redirecting when the insert receives a duplicate key exception instead of an extra round trip to the database to check for existence?

Comment: I am new to programming and node js I don't how to do that if you show how it can be done then I'll surely implement that because that is more efficient way of doing this.